# Include php script in Typo3 6.2

Tags: typo3

How can I render the result of a PHP script in TYPO3 6.2?

I tried with

```
page.10 {
  subparts.content = USER_INT
  subparts.content {
    includeLibs = fileadmin/script.php
    userFunc = user_printFunction
  }
}
```

and with others codes, function works in a new template but doesn´t work inside a page.

For example I want to insert text and below a php script.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

The includeLibs statement must be outside of any other TypoScript:

```
includeLibs = fileadmin/script.php
page.10 {
  subparts.content = USER_INT
  subparts.content {
    userFunc = user_printFunction
  }
}
```

See also the [examples in the official documentation](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/UserAndUserInt/Index.html#cobj-user-int-examples).

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you forgot to provide a funtion to call, see:

```
userFunc = user_printFunction->yourAwesomeFunction
```

Please note that includeLibs will NOT work outside any other TypoScript on Typo3 7 and up. On the other hand this worked out great:

```
page {
    12 = USER_INT
    12.userFunc = Deividas\FeAccounts->get
    12.includeLibs = fileadmin/FeAccounts.php
}
```

Use that includeLibs in the USER or USER_INT object.
I am using it for a small project and a small task. I would suggest you to create an global extension for your project. I guess that would be a cleaner way to create websites with Typo3.